# Simultaneously uploading image to storage and data for the image in the database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I am currently working on my first ever project with React.js - building an online shop. I am using Firebase Storage to upload the images of the products. I am able to upload them and successfully get their urls with another request after that.

Is it possible to get the url right when the upload is completed? I looked trough the documentation on uploadBytes function in hope that it returns a url that can be associated with the image, but it does not.

I want to upload the picture and know its url so that I can upload additional information to the db such as price, quantity, etc. using it's url as a reference and later on fetch the information from both the storage and db based on that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`uploadBytes()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#uploadbytes) method returns a Promise containing an [`UploadResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadresult.md#uploadresult_interface) Object which has two properties:

- `metadata`, which contains the metadata sent back from the server;
- `ref`, the reference that spawned this upload.

Therefore you can use the `ref` property to get the download URL. (Or you can directly use the reference you passed to the `uploadBytes()` method, since it is the same!)

For example:

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'some-child');

const bytes = new Uint8Array([0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21]);  // Example
uploadBytes(storageRef, bytes)
.then((uploadResult) => {
  return getDownloadURL(uploadResult.ref)
})
.then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped! I was missing the getDownloadURL step to find what I was looking for. You are a saviour!